# Best practice to import/export specific pages and posts

Tags: export, xml

I just started using a local host to work on my website on my desktop (using LAMP from Bitnami).

The native wordpress export feature for pages and posts lets me choose date range, but only a month at a time.

Is there a method for exporting selected pieces of updated content up to a live site from local host?

Comment: Please note that plugin recommendations are off-topic.What did you try so far?  I remember adding a "per day" option to the exporter in an [answer here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/199527/26350).

Comment: I think this is fine, since the question isn't about turn-key plugin, but about _practices_ of how people approach this (which can vary between plugins, tools, code, and so on).

Comment: Really - a technique professional developers must use all the time, and the only response is debate over the qualifications of the question?